# SAP Crystal reports is being printed on enterprise printer

Tags: drivers, printer, network-printer, sap

I have a problem with the print queue in SAP reports: Resources -

Windows 10 - 64 bit version,

Sap reports framework 32 bit version 13.0.26.3348

Sap reports framework 64 bit version 13.0.26.3348

Printers used for printing:

1. HP Lazerjet P4014
2. HP Lazerjet P4015
3. HP Lazerjet m600 601
4. HP Lazerjet m600 602

Bottom line: when using original drivers from the list of printers, only 1 printer worked correctly. In all other printers, there was a problem with printing like - when you click on the Print button - the printers printed the first two pages, then the printing stopped and either the printer did not print again or printed when it wanted)).

The connection to the printers was established both via the network and via a USB cable, the problem remained.

The problem was solved only in the above models by using the driver from HP LaserJet 400 M401 PCL6 Classic driver to 2,3,4 printers.

Also connecting the printer via YUSB to another PC and shared this printer. The printing went as it should, albeit with the printing, but without a single delay. If it is useful to someone, I decided to share my experience.

At the moment I am using new generation printers and I have the same problem again. The printer prints two sheets and puts a print on setting and only then prints, I tried my old methods but they did not work.

Printers:

HP Lazerjet M611

HP Lazerjet M612dn

Who faced this? can you help?

Comment: Do other applications allow you to print correctly on the printers?

Comment: Support Randomhero, did you try to print from other apps (Notepad, Word, Excel), do you observe the same behavior? Try to print both raw text (Notepad) and pagebreaks-separated (Word), it can matter for troubleshooting if pagebreaking work wrong (in SAP/non-SAP) or it is a general issue

Comment: it's  prints without stopping  for other apps such as MS WORD or Excel and Notepad the printers is working correctly.